# Why does the layout of my website change so drastically by adding www.

Tags: url, layout, web

When I look at my website using the url

### example.com

I get something like this:
[image]

But when I use the url

### www.example.com

I get this catastrophy:
[image]

Could anyone explain what I've done wrong?

Regards.

Comment: Are you able to add a url? screenshots wont really tell us much at this stage? Possibly a cache needing refreshing ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have some wrong paths. Or the htaccess is preventing from accessing the css

Comment: there doesnt seem to be a lack of styling being applied... just a certain rule(s) that has not been applied or something.?
unless your css is controlled / generated via the server side and the www is messing up that code?

Comment: Nope. No idea what the issue is, at the moment I'm just rewriting all urls from www.example.com straight to example.com which seems to be a short term fix. I guess there must be some issue with how the css is being implemented.

Comment: when viewing the css files directly on the www vs no www... is anything missing.. you should be able to spot it this way.. as in navigate to and compare the css files themself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a possible answer... By the looks of the your screen shots..
Check your pages "Zoom" setting as in the browser setting..
this is saved per domain, so make sure its 100%

Comment: That would explain why things look so small, why the spacing/centering is out and the styling is still being applied

Comment: Best to confirm these issues quickly with another web browser on the same PC or check another pc

Comment: I zoomed out in the second image so you could see just how out of line everything is. Normally both pages come up at the same zoom rate.

Comment: Than has to be something affecting the css in some way, as suggest above with the htaccess. , perhaps quickly remove/rename it to rule out anything there ... if your able to not require it to display the site.

otherwise if you can host a copy for people to scan over it for you

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make any sense. Do you have an .htaccess rule preventing access to certain resources via the www.example.com hostname?

Comment: Quite possibly, I had better check .htaccess to see if I've done something damaging. Thanks.